# Java - Check if the digits in number are distinct or not?

Tags: java

Is there a JDK method for knowing if I have all non distinct-digits like `111`, `222`, `333`.

I know we can do it by looping, but is there a better way?

Comment: guys this cannot be narrowed down, Its not broad question rather its specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [String::matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) with a regex `(\d)\1*` like this :

```
boolean distinct = String.valueOf(111).matches("(\\d)\\1*");
```

Comment: thank man for quick solution, still 9 more mins restriction to accept

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method to do that for you, however, another variant would be:

```
public static boolean someMethodName(String input){          
       return input.chars().distinct().limit(2).count() == 1;
}
```

You can then perform validation on the parameter before operating on it if needed. i.e whether it's `null` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think regex can help you, but before man said not correct. It'll help you.

```java
String.valueOf( yourNumber ).matches( "\\d{2,}" )
```

This's correct regex for your issue.